# Перенос текста в таблице

Tags: html, css

```
<table width=200 border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>
                  К о н т е н т
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Обычная таблица с указанной шириной. Слова автоматически переносятся на новую строку. 
А как сделать эту величину абсолютной? Просто, если в указанном примере написать длинный набор символов без пробела, то таблица растянется. Как сделать, чтобы даже безпробельный текст переносился, не растягивая по ширине таблицу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML перенос слов какими-либо тегами осуществить не удастся, а пользоваться вспомогательным кодом нет смысла, потому что результат будет отображен далеко не во всех браузерах, то есть не будет соблюдена его кросс-браузерность. Перенос слов можно производить вручную, но результат не понравится ни вам, ни вашим посетителям, потому как наличие большого количества черточек в тексте страницы не делают его привлекательным. Оставьте идею переноса слов – экономьте свое драгоценное время.

Свойство word-wrap: break-word; по моему работает как не странно только в IE)
Если и будут возникать длинные слова, то можно перенести вручную, но это наверняка единичные случаи.

Comment: Соглашусь со всем вышесказанным, только вот **word-wrap** работает во всех браузерах, хотя CSS-свойством его можно назвать с большой натяжкой.

Comment: @Deonis 
Попробуйте в chrom)) Я только что попробовал для проверки)) На сколько я помню это решение от Microsoft.
Процитирую с Вашей ссылки:

"Свойство word-wrap указывает, переносить или нет длинные слова, которые не помещаются по ширине в заданную область. Данное свойство носит черновой характер и при валидации документа на CSS3 выдает ошибку."

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то думаю, что вам надо прочитать, про [word-wrap](http://htmlbook.ru/css/word-wrap)